# MFMailComposeViewController not getting dismissed

Tags: ios, xcode

I've implemented MFMessageComposeViewController in my code but while I can send an email now, the view controller does not get dismissed when saving the draft, deleting it or even sending the email. I've also tried adding breakpoints and the code to dismiss it doesn't even get run.

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender {

Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));

if(mailClass != nil)
{
    if ([mailClass canSendMail])
    {
        [self displayComposerSheet];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }

}
else
{
    [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
}
}

- (void)displayComposerSheet
{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foomail@foo.foo"];

[picker setEditing:YES];
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
}

- (void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
NSString *address = @"mailto:enquiries@moray.it";

NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", address];
email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
 }

-(void)mailComposeController:picker didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delegate before calling presentModalViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `picker.mailComposeDelegate = self` before presenting your modal view.
It may help you.

Comment: I did that above, but couldn't set it as answered. Thanks, anyway!